# Searchlogic - searching for exact match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

I am using Searchlogic to perform searches on my 'report' index page.

```
<% form_for @search do |f| %>
  Search:
  <%= f.text_field :report_id_like, :size=> 50 %>
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Currently, if I search for a report with report id '5', I get a list of entries with report id containing '5'.

I would like to get only the record with report_id '5' when I input '5'.

Any suggestion?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:

Instead of :

```
<%= f.text_field :report_id_like, :size=> 50 %>
```

Put:

```
<%= f.text_field :report_id_equals, :size=> 50 %>
```

Hope it might be of help to someone else